# How to collect a new list from a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, loops

Let's say I have a list

```
x = ["angela lopez", "kimmy kardahshian", "frank moses", "john peter"]
```

Now from this list up here, I wan to get four letters from the first words and 3 letters reversed of the second word. Like
angela(first four) - ange
lopez(reversed first three) - pol

now for each of them, then I combine the generated name and make it a list. e.g ["angepol", "....","....","...."]..

I tried to code it like this

```
y = []
y = [string[:3] for string in x]
print ("The created list is confirmed as: ", y)
z= []
z = [string[7:9] for string in x]
print ("The created list is confirmed as: ", z)
```

But didn't work as I wanted so I didn't finish it.

I also tried to split the list then do it one after each other. But that will not work too.

Comment: _But didn't work as I wanted_ --> Please [edit] your question and add the actual output that you get.

Comment: Something to the effect of: `[f"{first[:4]}{last[2::-1]}" for first, last in (s.split() for s in x)]`

Comment: Or: `[a[:4] + b[2::-1] for a, b in map(str.split, x)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for z:

```
z=[i.split()[1][:3][::-1] for i in x]
```

and given your y as:

```
y = [string[:4] for string in x]
```

you can get the result as following:

```
res=[y[i]+z[i] for i in range(len(y))]

>>> print(res)

['angepol', 'kimmrak', 'fransom', 'johntep']
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thank you. But how about if i want z to do the function of y.

Comment: Like lopez should display has lop , capturing the first three letters without reversing it

Comment: If you don't want the reverse, jus try this: `z=[i.split()[1][:3] for i in x]`

Comment: Don't worry, I have got that too. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
names = ["angela lopez", "kimmy kardahshian", "frank moses", "john peter"]

print([parts[0][:3] + parts[1][:3][::-1] for parts in map(str.split, names)])
```

Output:

```
['angpol', 'kimrak', 'frasom', 'johtep']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved using the map function:

The map function syntax is as follows:

```
map (function, iterable)
```

so you could create a function to format your data like so:

```
names = ["angela lopez", "kimmy kardahshian", "frank moses", "john peter"]
def formatText(string):
    return (string[:4] + string.split(" ")[1][2::-1])
names = list(map(formatText, names))
```

This code outputs:

```
['angpol', 'kimrak', 'frasom', 'johtep']
```

yes, you could do this in a one liner, using lambda or a list comprehension but this way does the same thing but remains more readable.